# can i have a record with 2 lookups to a single object show up on both related lists?

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com, lookup

So, my title may be misleading here, so apologies....

i have a lead record with 2 different look up fields to the account object, but different records. I know I can have the lead appear on the accounts if i have a related list for each lookup field. Is there a way to combine them into a single RL? so that if 2 leads are associated with a single account via a a different lookup, they get put in the same RL?

else, i might need to do a VF, apex thing....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your business logic. But if you have **always** one lookup to **null**, you might create a **3th Account lookup** which can be populated by trigger(not sure you can do that by workflow). That means you can display only the related list of the 3th lookup which gonna merge both. In other case, I'm afraid you have to create a custom VF.

Answer (score 1):

Standard UI will not allow you to do a single related list out of many child relationships. To solve this problem, you would need to do something with custom visualforce and apex.

Comment: <apex:inputCurses value = "bleeep" />